# Whats '&' in the statement means?

Tags: c++, pointers

```
bool ok =true;
ok &= (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);
```

1.whats the "&" means in this code?
2.Is it assignment of any variable?

Comment: Are you having a problem locating the chapter in your C++ textbook which explains this, and other operators? Which C++ textbook are you using?

Comment: Once you read up on `&`, you'll discover that it's a waste of time here: the code above could easily be rewritten as `bool ok = (a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1);`

Answer (score 0):

In this context, `&=` is the [bitwise AND-assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment).  The value of the variable on the lefthand side (`ok`) is AND'ed with the value of the expression on the righthand side (`(a[i] - a[i - 1] <= 1)`), and the result is then assigned back to the lefthand variable.